# Error when session expired and ajax request execute in Keycloak?

Tags: java, cors, wildfly, keycloak

I have a problem.
When I use Keysloak to authorization, ceases to work correctly redirect to the home page or to the login page when Ajax request call, at the time when the session has expired.

**This error i have in browser console:**

XMLHttpRequest cannot load _http://dc09-apps-06:8090/auth/realms/azovstal/protocol/openid-connect/auth?…ml&state=60%2F01fc2e79-6fc0-46b8-9f83-39b7421fedf9&login=true&scope=openid. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin '_http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access.

I add in Keycloak admin console, in the client setting, Web Origins=http://localhost:8080, and enabled cors in app, but still not working.

So it should work, or it's a bug or something I don't understand?

Comment: Why do you think that there should be a relationship between the HttpSession lifetime and the authentication state?

Comment: @Steve C i dont now, but without Keycloak i can catched error that session has expired. With Keycloak i get http code 302 for ajax request and stay on the same page, without, i get http code 200 and redirect to home page.